# If a class has more than once constructor which of them gets called?

Tags: constructor

Like the titles says, if I have multiple constructors (which is not good practice), which of them gets called?

Comment: In what language? Typically it would be the one whose signature matches the arguments you passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you hear that it was bad practice?
You can only have one constructor with a certain parameter list order so the one that gets called is the one specified by the argument you've passed in.

```
public class Test {
   public Test() {...}
   public Test(String str, int x) {...}
}
```

Say later on you call:

```
Test test = new Test("Hello", 46);
```

The constructor that gets called is this one:

```
public Test(String str, int x) {...}
```

Where the String `"Hello"` and the number `46` are passed in `str` and `x` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

What programming language?
Everything depends on the language.

For Delphi, for example, it is valid to have to have multiple constructors. Even with the same name and with different parameters (both in quantity and type). In this case builders should be overloaded.

```
constructor TMyClass.Create overrride;
begin
   // Code here
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create(Value: integer); override;
begin
   // Code here
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create(Value1: integer; Value2: string); override;
begin
  // Code here
end;
```

The compiler on their own know which one is going to run.
Indeed, it is even legal to do this:

```
constructor TMyClass.Create(Value3: double);
begin
   Create(Random (9), 'Hello');
end;
```

Ie invoke one another.

The magic of the compiler decides when and what has to execute. And I have understood that this is in all LOO. ;)